# Creating a custom grid board (as seen in board games)

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android GUI design. I'm trying to create a board as seen below. The cells can have different colors, and should be clickable with a toast shown, such attributes. My current code has major problems. How can generate this type of view? I would suggest let's start from scratch as this might be very simple to create and my code is a mess. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

private GridView list;
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gridview);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
        data.add(i+"-"+j);
    }
    GridViewCustomAdapter adapter = new GridViewCustomAdapter(this, data);

    list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

and

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GridViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> items;

    static Activity mActivity;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public GridViewCustomAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> tempTitle) {
        mActivity = activity;
        items = tempTitle;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public final int getCount() {

        return items.size();

    }

    @Override
    public final Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public final long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = null;

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        Button tv = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        tv.setText(items.get(position));

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll post a more thorough answer later but check out [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)

Comment: Thanks. Please try to make the code as stupid as possible!

Comment: You bet! I also wrote a custom View that's a [grid](https://github.com/davidmascharka/LIPS/blob/master/src/com/mascharka/indoorlocalization/GridView.java). Maybe not exactly what you're looking for but you'd change the onTouchEvent() method a little bit to get the functionality you want. A lot of that code you could get rid of for your purpose (ScaleListener, setUserPointCoords, setMapUri, setDisplayMap, and their member variables).

Comment: Your code is too complicated lol. Can you simplify it?:) It should be setting a grid layout with a picture/square shown inside each,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example using Buttons. You can add resizing, a ScrollView, whatever.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TableLayout table;
    private static final int TABLE_WIDTH = 12;
    private static final int TABLE_HEIGHT = 8;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_root);

        // Populate the table with stuff
        for (int y = 0; y < TABLE_HEIGHT; y++) {
            final int row = y;
            TableRow r = new TableRow(this);
            table.addView(r);
            for (int x = 0; x < TABLE_WIDTH; x++) {
                final int col = x;
                Button b = new Button(this);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "You clicked (" + row + "," + col + ")",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                r.addView(b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your layout file is just

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/view_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! The 12x8 table does not fit on the screen though. How can I make all of it fit the screen (resize automatically to screen size)?

Comment: or it is hard, how can make them smaller and add scroll bar?

Comment: You could add android:shrinkColumns="*" to the TableLayout xml to shrink the buttons

Comment: thanks for the hint. Can I apply the same thing, but vertically? (e.g. shrinkRows!, but we don't have this)